# How to delete lines from a table created by a custom module?

Tags: 6, forms, database

I'm working on a custom module that has an admin form designed to contain a number of values.
age 21 => value, age 22 => value, etc.

The issue I'm having is that while I can add information to the table I've created through my form, I'm only supposed to have 1 possible value per age.
I dont know how to delete the old value before the new one is added.

This is what I have that adds info to my table successfully:

```
/**
* Saving Score administration settings and DB information
*/
function savingsscore_admin_form() {
  $form = array();
$form['savings_ages'] = array(
  '#type' => 'fieldset', 
  '#title' => t('Saving Ages'), 
  '#weight' => -1, 
  '#collapsible' => TRUE, 
  '#collapsed' => FALSE,
  '#description' => t('Description of fields in this fieldset here'),
);
$form['savings_ages']['saving_age21'] = array(
'#type' => 'textfield',
'#title' => t('21'),
'#size' => 10,
'#maxlength' => 10,
'#default_value' => '10.85',
);
  return $form;
}

/**
* Handle submission of Admin forms
*/
function savingsscore_admin_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
db_query("INSERT INTO {savingfactors} (saving_age21)
VALUES ('%s')",
  $form_state['values']['saving_age21']);

drupal_set_message(t('Your form has been saved.'));
}
```

I know that what happens next should start like:

```
 db_query("DELETE FROM
```

But I dont know what I should add next, I'm uncertain of the syntax.
Any help or links to documentation would be much appreciated

Thanks
Stephanie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will find an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825337/help-with-db-query-in-drupal-if-exists-update-else-insert).

Basically you can use Drupal's [drupal_write_record()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_write_record/6) to let Drupal handle that.

Or you can run a SELECT query first and an UPDATE or INSERT based on SELECT's result.

**EDIT:**

Based on information gathered in comments, it seems that the "savingfactors" table has several columns and only one row. If the row is already present, with any value, then a simple UPDATE query is enough. Here's an example:

```
function savingsscore_admin_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  db_query("UPDATE {savingfactors} SET saving_age21 = '%s'", $form_state['values']['saving_age21']);
  drupal_set_message(t('Your form has been saved.'));
}
```

That way you overwrite only saving_age21 field, ignoring others.

You can do the same with any other field you want to save.

There's an initial requirement: the row must exist. You can manually create it with a db client software, or you can implement Drupal's hook_install() inside your module .install file.

Comment: Thank you for replying, drupal_write_record makes sense but my form will have over 80 fields, and the examples I've seen dont have so many fields.
If you stil think it's a viable answer, how would I use it with so many fields?

Comment: I'm not sure I gave you a good advice. Before fixing my answer: how is your "savingfactors" table structured? Are those "age 21", "age 22" columns names, or are they values in a row?

Comment: age21 and age22 are column names (not sure of a better method, but thats a different post), I wil be going from age21 - age65. Thank you again for your time.

Comment: Your table will have multiple rows or only one?

Comment: just one row (ideally)

Comment: I modified my answer accordingly. I hope it helps. :)

Comment: Thank you very much this works! (next I'll be looking for better ways to build my DB's ;) )
Thanks!!